# I created a todo app using react and firestore but it is storing my values as string and i want them to be stored as number

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a todo app using react and firestore but it is storing my values as string and i want them to be stored as number. Can someone tell what to do, i tried adding Number() but it didn't work. So if anyone could explain what i am doing wrong or how to do it i will be really grateful.

Code :
function SignUp() {

```
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])
const [form, setForm] = useState({
title: Number(""),
desc: "",
})
const [popupActive, setPopupActive] = useState(false)

const recipesCollectionRef = collection(db, "recipes")

useEffect(() => {
onSnapshot(recipesCollectionRef, snapshot => {
  setRecipes(snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    return {
      id: doc.id,
      viewing: false,
      ...doc.data()
    }
  }))
})
}, [])

const handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault()

if (
  !form.title ||
  !form.desc 
) {
  alert("Please fill out all fields")
  return
}

addDoc(recipesCollectionRef, form)

setForm({
  title: Number(""),
  desc: "",
})

setPopupActive(false)
}


const removeRecipe = id => {
deleteDoc(doc(db, "recipes", id))
}

return (

<div className="App">
<label>Upload Your Slots</label>

  <button onClick={() => setPopupActive(!popupActive)}>Add Slots</button>

  <div className="recipes">
    { recipes.map((recipe, i) => (
      <div className="recipe" key={recipe.id}>
        <h3>{ recipe.title }</h3>

        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: recipe.desc }}></p>

        { recipe.viewing && <div>
          
        </div>}

        <div className="buttons">
          
          <button className="remove" onClick={() => removeRecipe(recipe.id)}>Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>

  { popupActive && <div className="popup">
    <div className="popup-inner">
     

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label><br></br>From</label>
          <input 
          placeholder="Upload Your Slots In HH:MM 24hr Format"
            type="number" 
            value={form.title} 
            onChange={e => setForm({...form, title: e.target.value})} />
        </div>
```